# trouble catching enter keystroke in javascript

Tags: javascript

this seems simple, but i can't make it work.

i'm trying to catch an enter keystroke, and run some code, but when i hit enter, the page refreshes and nothing happens.

here's my script

```
function GetChar(event) {
    var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == '13') {
        var cQuery = document.getElementById('searchfield').value;
        var cURL = 'ProductGrid.aspx?Query=' + escape(cQuery);
        document.location = cURL;
    };
```

wheni hit enter the page is refreshed, and the search field is cleared, but it doesn't run any of the code in the if block

Comment: I see your function, but it's not clear when this function is being called. What is the context?

Comment: the function is being called with onkeydown on a textbox. i tried adding an alert before the if statement alerting the keycode var value, which confirmed it is being called, and pressing enter resulted in keycode being 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `searchfield` is inside a Form, this Form gets submitted, causing your code not to run.

You can either remove the Form and just use the Input-field, or you have to stop the Form-Submit by using somehting like this:

```
<form onSubmit="this.preventDefault&&this.preventDefault();this.returnValue=false;return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using keypress event? Explorer doesn't fire the keypress event for Enter...

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: i'm using onkeydown, and I'm testing in FF

Answer (score 0):

Returning `false` from your function could do the job.